# Sequelize - Rename column with index & constraint

Tags: migration, sequelize.js

I want create migration with Sequelize to rename column with camelCase to have a database with column in snake_case.

I use Sequelize to create migration and use migration.

```js
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
      return queryInterface.renameColumn('my_some_table', 'totoId', 'toto_id');
  },

  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
      //
  }
};
```

But... I have a unique constraint on this column (totoId) and name column, named **my_some_table_name_totoId_uindex**, and I also have  an index on this column (totoId).

How I can force renaming column who have a unique constraint and one index?

Comment: I think in PostgreSQL it just does a `ALTER TABLE` and works without any other conerns: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-rename-column SQLite likely still an issue. Maybe SQLite too? https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html Not sure.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to drop all the constraints, rename the column and then add the constraints back. With a single constraint on `totoId` it would look something like this:

```
// 1) drop constraint
queryInterface.removeConstraint('my_some_table', 'my_constraint');

// 2) rename column
queryInterface.renameColumn('my_some_table', 'totoId', 'toto_id');

// 3) add constraint back
queryInterface.addConstraint('my_some_table', ['toto_id'], {
    type: 'unique',
    name: 'my_constraint'
});
```

Remember that migrations should be atomic operations. <s>So you should create 3 migrations in that order.</s> Or even better, as @Santilli pointed out in the comments, you could create a transaction.
This will prevent from any change to be applied if one of the queries fails:

```
return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(async (transaction) => {
  await queryInterface.removeConstraint("my_some_table", "my_constraint", {
    transaction,
  });
  await queryInterface.renameColumn("my_some_table", "totoId", "toto_id", {
    transaction,
  });
  await queryInterface.addConstraint("my_some_table", ["toto_id"], {
    type: "unique",
    name: "my_constraint",
    transaction,
  });
});
```

Also, remember to create a transaction to revert the changes in the `down` function.

Comment: I can't use SQL query directly :/

Comment: @pirmax you can just use the .query call directly in the migrations

Comment: "Remember that migrations should be atomic operations. So you should create 3 migrations in that order." any reason not to use transactions and a single migration? Current docs exemplify it: https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/migrations.html

Comment: Actually, a transaction is even a better solution. I updated the answer to point it out.